# XML processing issue migrating from Oracle 9i to 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

The output of below code varies on Oracle 9i (9.2.0.8.0) and 11g (11.2.0.3.0):

```sql
DECLARE 
  var       XMLType; 
  doc       DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument; 
  ndoc      DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMNode; 
  buf       VARCHAR2(2000);

  pd       DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument; 
  v_parser dbms_xmlparser.parser;
BEGIN 
  var := XMLType('<PERSON><NAME>                </NAME></PERSON>');

  -- Create DOMDocument handle
  doc     := DBMS_XMLDOM.newDOMDocument(var); 
  ndoc    := DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(doc);

  DBMS_XMLDOM.writeToBuffer(ndoc, buf);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Before:'||buf);


  v_parser := dbms_xmlparser.newparser;
  DBMS_XMLPARSER.PARSEBUFFER(v_parser, buf);

  pd := dbms_xmlparser.getdocument(v_parser);
  ndoc    := DBMS_XMLDOM.makeNode(pd);

  DBMS_XMLDOM.writeToBuffer(ndoc, buf);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('now:'||buf);

END;
/
```

On 9i its output is:

```html
Before:<PERSON>
  <NAME/>
</PERSON>

now:<PERSON>
  <NAME/>
</PERSON>
```

On 11g I get:

```html
Before:<PERSON>
  <NAME>                </NAME>
</PERSON>

now:<PERSON>
  <NAME>                </NAME>
</PERSON>
```

I need to have the 9i output when I execute this on 11g, what changes should I do. I tried using parser but it didn't work.

Comment: I had to use the code-snippet as the text was not getting accepted using the code block.

Comment: Significant whitespace is part of the document content and should be preserved [(ref)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html); that it was stripped in 9i seems to have been a bug (6151936?). What it's doing now seems to be 'correct'. But that article also refers to `setPreserveWhitespace(false)`, which doesn't appear to do what you want; and the XLST transform it suggests doesn't remove whitespace within the node either.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this clears my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to fix the code that generated white space 
Issue is resolved once the below code

```
var := XMLType('<PERSON><NAME>                </NAME></PERSON>');
```

is rewritten as below:

```
var := XMLType('<PERSON><NAME></NAME></PERSON>');
```